# Linux upgrade stops because of invalid udev extension in sources list

Tags: server, 18.04, upgrade, udev

Hoping people server smarter than me can help out on this one. We have 3 (one load balancer and two servers) Ubuntu servers on 18.04. I was trying to bring them up to 22 (slowly) and got blocked pretty quickly. I've done 18.04 to 22.04 on staging servers and everything was fine. I tried to do the `sudo apt update` on the load balancer and got pretty quickly blocked saying it was ignoring the udev file in the `sources.list.d` folder. I have read a lot of suggestions of just removing these files but then one other forum said that it couldn't understand a `.deb` file can be fatal.

Here's what I see when I run this command.
[image: sudo apt update results]

Now thinking it's okay, trying to run `sudo apt upgrade` gives me this:
[image: sudo apt upgrade]

Has anyone ran into this? Looking at the udev project, it sounds like a big deal. I wasn't the one who installed these servers so I have no idea why they did it.

Any tips? Thanks in advanced.

Comment: There is no sensible reason to have .deb files in that directory, but the message is just a Note, and ignoring the file is proper and in itself won't cause a problem. That is not what is causing the problems in the 2nd screenshot. Speaking of, please don't post pictures of text. Copy and paste the text.

Comment: Got it. I'll do that in the future. Sorry about that!

Comment: [Ubuntu 18.04 LTS has reached the end of it's *standard* support life](https://fridge.ubuntu.com/2023/05/13/extended-security-maintenance-for-ubuntu-18-04-bionic-beaver-begins-31-may-2023/) thus is now off-topic here unless your question is specific to helping you move to a supported release of Ubuntu.  Ubuntu 18.04 ESM support is available, but not on-topic here, see https://askubuntu.com/help/on-topic  See also https://ubuntu.com//blog/18-04-end-of-standard-support